# mysql string concatenation returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql, string, concatenation

im trying to concatenate 3 columns in a select query to show in one column in the results. the column is called DelPostalName and for some reason always shows a '0' when i run the select query. like its trying to add up the strings but theres not actual numbers to add. ive been googling string concatenation and this seems to be the correct syntax. any ideas?

```
isc_orders.ordShipFirstName + ' ' + isc_orders.ordshiplastname + isc_orders.ordshipcompany as DelPostalName,
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The result appears as zero since you are trying to arithmetically add the strings to each other.

The correct method for concatenating strings in MySQL is using the `CONCAT(str1, str2, str3)` function.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is the manual for the function.

PS: if you want to concate with a seperator use `CONCAT_WS()` - also in the same manual

Answer (score 3):

You should use `CONCAT` (as a few people have mentioned) like this:

```
CONCAT(isc_orders.ordShipFirstName,' ',
isc_orders.ordshiplastname,' ',
isc_orders.ordshipcompany)
AS DelPostalName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate columns/strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for concatenation, not `+` :)