# select distinct u.id, u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name , u.company_name from user_master u gives wrong result

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

My Application is working on java + MSSQL and MySQL.below query works for MSSQL but not for MySql.
In mysql when i write query as below it gives me wrong result

**Query**

```
select distinct u.id, u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name as 'FullName', u.company_name  from user_master u
```

Its gives me Below result

**Result**

```
id  FullName company_name
1   0        abc
2   0        comp2
```

**Expected Result**

```
id  FullName      company_name
1   shah priya    abc
2   xyz test      comp2
```

can any body help me to do it

if i write below query then its working fine

```
select distinct u.id, concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as 'FullName', u.company_name
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185192/mysql-string-concatenation-returns-0

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `+` operator for concatenation. Instead you should use concat function.

`+` means addition here.

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

As you have added tag for SQL Server, the following will help you

Your table

```
SELECT 'PRIYA' FNAME, 'RAMAN' LNAME
INTO #TEMP
```

[image]

Your result

```
SELECT *,FNAME + ' ' + LNAME AS FULLNAME 
FROM #TEMP
```

[image]

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85020/1 (If any error occurs loading press RUNSQL)

Comment: I need only three field.dont want whole record

Comment: SELECT distinct u.id, u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name as AS  FullName, u.company_name from user_master u 
@Sejal Rudani

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to stay with the concat() notation, that is much clearer IMHO, if you just want it to works in MySQL.

If there is a need to compatibility between the queries, maybe you should use an high level query language like HQL, then let the MSSQL and MYSQL drivers do the translation into their specific sql idiom. See [documentation of Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation) for this.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct u.id, CONCAT_WS(' ',u.first_name,u.last_name) as FullName, u.company_name from user_master u

CONCAT & CONCAT_WS is an built in string function in mysql